# Laravel not showing image in view

Tags: laravel, image, web

I have stored the path of the user image profile in a database field, when i try to displayed in a view it doesn´t show anything I tried doing this

```
@foreach($user as $users)
<img src="{{$users->fotografia}}"  class="user-image" alt="User Image">
@endforeach
```

and in the view shows me the url from the image instead of the image  \10.56.5.92\Fotos_Empleados\10044.jpg

the image is stored in a server image do I need to do a symbolic Link? and If so what would be the right code because the image aren´t stored in folder public or anything like it

Answer (score 0):

> Hey, Try this take a look at the examples:

```
echo public_path();
// C:\Users\XYZ\laravel\public
```

In Your Case try this

```
public_path()."/"."YourDirectoryNameIfExist/{{$users->fotografia}}"
```

***VS***

```
echo url('/');
// http://localhost/laravel/public
```